# bootstrap modal not animating on close

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the demo code like this

```
<!-- Small modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm">Small modal</button>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            Hello
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is showing the modal on click of button with the animation, but on click of close button its not hiding the modal with animation. Instead its hiding immediately. What I need to fix here?

I am using full css file of bootstrap 3.1.1 and modal.js file.

Comment: i think it work fine. http://www.bootply.com/131725

Comment: What browser are you using? Your browser might not support CSS animations.

Comment: @TheShellfishMeme I am using chrome. its showing animation on show.. but not on hide

Comment: @shin Yes it is showing animation on close when I am attaching the whole bootstrap.js file. But for only modal.js its not showing on close.

Comment: Ok Found the answer I also need to add jquery plugin Transitions.